# Ant include dir contents in fileset whilst flattening path/to/dir

Tags: ant

I'm trying to get Ant to include a directory in a `fileset` without having to resort to long-winded solutions (unless I really have to). Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

```
<copy todir="targetdir">
    <fileset dir="@{source}">
        <include name="**/somedir/" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

I'm trying to get the *contents* of `somedir`, including all sub-directories, from `@{source}/path/to/somedir` whilst not knowing explicitly where `somedir` is.

So, say `somedir` has two sub-directories, `sub1` and `sub2`, the goal is to have these two directories end up in `targetdir` (including all of their contents).

I can't just flatten the whole thing since that would kill the directory structures within the sub-directories, and the current solution outlined above leaves me with `targetdir` containing `somedir`, rather than just its contents.

I don't want to move the directories afterwards since theoretically i could have multiple includes in the fileset with various paths, all requiring the same copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this using [mappers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) inside the copy element.  The easiest way is to use a [cut dirs mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#cutdirs-mapper) but you will need to know the amount of dirs you want to cut from the path.  You could also use a [regexp mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper) to remove the leading dirs:

```
<regexpmapper from="^(([^/]*/)+?)/somedir/(.*)$$" to="\2"/>
```

The above is untested but should define 2 capturing groups, everything before somedir and the bit after somedir, and replace is just the second group.